# What statistic would I use to explain the discrepancy between two binary variables?

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, binary-data

I have 3 variables in a large dataset: whether students passed their multiple choice portion of their final (binary: pass-fail), whether they passed qualitative portion (binary: pass-fail), and student test taking preference (unordered categorical: multiple choice, written, no preference). The point-biserial correlation between final exam variables is .78, and I'm interested in exploring how much student reason explains *the discrepancy between these exams (e.g., passing one portion but not another), not exam performance itself.*

**Is there a statistic to account for the discrepancies between two categorical variables to explain the variance in why there isn't a perfect relationship between the two binary variables** (e.g., the .22 in this example)?

**If not, how would you recommend to structure this problem to see how much student test preference explains them passing one section but failing another?**

My intuition says to set up a logistic regression with two outcomes (no discrepancy - discrepancy) and try to predict the outcomes. If I did that though and found that the pseudo-R squared was .2, would I be justified in saying that "student test preference explains 20% of the variability between students passing just one section of the test"?